# Is conv2d using random filters? Is that good for the NN?

Tags: filter, conv-neural-network, pytorch

If I am using `nn.Conv2d(in_dim, out_dim, kernel_size, bias=False)` command in PyTorch, then the function creates as many filters as specified by out_dim. Are these filters random? Is it not be better to customize these filters? Does someone have a method for this?

Or is it better to use the random filter generated by this function?

Done in PyTorch, python.

Thanks

Comment: [This link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-a-conv2d-layer-and-linear-layer/16055) shows the default initialization code. However, in deep learning (where we use this `Conv2d` for creating CNNs), the filters are learnt using a dataset, so I'm not sure what you are asking. If you want to have a custom filter purely for image/signal processing purposes, then you could modify the weights manually using `conv.weight` (search about this) where `conv = nn.Conv2d(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these filters random? Is it not be better to customize these filters? Does someone have a method for this?

Yes, they are pretty random, made via the [initialization function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html) used for the [Conv2d](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/029a968212b018192cb6fc64075e68db9985c86a/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L49).

This may change but by default, `nn.Conv2d` uses `init.kaiming_uniform_`. You can tweak it as:

```
conv_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, out_dim, kernel_size, bias=False)
torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_(conv_layer.weight)
```

The concept is to learn the weights while training, so these random values at first will alter and become learned tensor values.